# How to start Clojure REPL from anywhere?

Tags: java, clojure, read-eval-print-loop

I can start Clojure REPL from directory when it was unpacked (C:\Program Files\clojure-1.6.0) by this command in command line:

```
java -cp clojure-1.6.0.jar clojure.main
```

but anytime I want to start REPL I have to enter directory C:\Program Files\clojure-1.6.0, so I create bat file with next content:

```
java -cp C:\Program Files\clojure-1.6.0\clojure-1.6.0.jar clojure.main
```

and put it to directory wich includes in PATH variable. I expect that it will run Clojure REPL, but instead of it I get an error

> Error: Could not find or load main class
>   Files\clojure-1.6.0\clojure-1.6.0.jar

And I don't find in internet how to fix it. Please help.

Comment: Maven way: `mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=clojure.main`, in a project with `org.clojure:clojure` as a dependency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this must be a space issue in "Program Files". try to have the entire path quoted like this:

`java -cp "C:\Program Files\clojure-1.6.0\clojure-1.6.0.jar" clojure.main`

Comment: O, thanx! I often forget about spaces!

Comment: I would suggest to not use clojure directly, just use leinigen's repl task

Answer (score 2):

I think you very likely want to install [Leiningen](http://leiningen.org/).

You can then start a Clojure repl from anywhere with the command `lein repl`.

> Note: lein takes care of getting and managing the Clojure jar for you --- you don't need
>   to "install" Clojure. Just use lein and it takes care of everything. :)